# How to Normalize a table where a column references multiple rows of a different column in the same table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-normalization

I am trying to create a table that lists different applications and if they integrate with other applications on that list.

```
ID  SKU     NAME            Integrations
1   pdk1    hubspot crm pdk3,pdk4,pdk5
2   pdk2    sugar crm   pdk5
3   pdk3    pipedrive   pdk1
4   pdk4    quickbooks  pdk1
5   pdk5    mailchimp   pdk1,pdk2
```

How can I normalize the integrations column?

Comment: You should move away from the paradigm of storing CSV data in the `Integrations` column.

Comment: @DeanArmstrong . . . Please show the results that you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "references" & what do you mean by "normalize" & why are you stuck? Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: Moreover normalization questions are faqs here. (Although they are mostly poorly answered.) Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: What the 2 earlier comments meant to say was "Hi Dean and welcome to Stack Overflow", and then answer the question as the other two members did below, both of which are good responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relations between SKUs in your example are "many-to-many" (M:M). Storing multiple comma-separated values in the column violates the first normal form (1NF). Hence you need normalise table and model M:M relation using an additional link table.

SKU table

```
SKU
---
ID  SKU     NAME        
1   pdk1    hubspot crm 
2   pdk2    sugar crm   
3   pdk3    pipedrive   
4   pdk4    quickbooks  
5   pdk5    mailchimp
```

Link table

```
SKU_INTEGRATION
---------------
ID  INTEGRATED_WITH_ID
1   3
1   4
1   5
2   5
3   1
4   1
5   1
5   2
```

You may have a look on the book "[Programming with databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2956300806)" which covers the topics of normalization, modeling of different types of links etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select id, sku, name,
       regexp_split_to_table(integrations) as integration
from t;
```

This isn't exactly "normalized" but it removes the use of a delimited string to represent multiple values.